# keyboard shortcut to insert text at the end of several lines of same length instead of 10,12s/$/pattern_to_be_inserted/gc

Tags: insert-mode, line-numbers, selection

to insert the same text inside several lines in one particular line `<ctrl>` + `<v>` to select the line and then `<shift>` + `<i>` to insert a texte BEFORE the particular column. Is there a way to do the same but insert a text AFTER the particular column, at the end of lines of same length instead of using `10,12s/$/pattern_to_be_inserted/gc`?

Comment: do the same but with `A`, e.g. `Ctrl-V jj$` then `A` and add some text...

Comment: Many thank @MaximKim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select visual block, press `$A` and add text -- it would be added to the ends of all lines in that visual block.
2. Select visual block, press `A` and add text -- it would be added to the end of the block for each line.

[image]

Comment: Ok ... I have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer. You were to quick! ;) Remind me if I forget

Comment: @ecjb no problem, have fun!